# How to use create DataContext instance in Console project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, console-application, asp.net-core-3.1

Let's say I have two projects:

Persistence project which is a class library and this is where I put my DataContext class.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

   // code removed for brevity
}
```

And I have another Console project which uses the above project for data access. How do I create an instance of DataContext? I think I need to implement Dependency Injection in my console but can't figure out how.

By the way, I am using .NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To paraphrase the Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

using (var context = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert but I will tell you what I have done in my .net core cosnole application, please suggest me if there is any other better way of doing this.

Declare the class like this.

```
class TestContext: DbContext
{
    IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
    public TestContext(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public DbSet<YourEntity> YourEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("connection_string"));
    }
}
```

Create instance of `TestContext` in the Main method.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            _configuration = builder.Build();

public static IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
TestContext context = new TestContext(_configuration);
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't want to create another context class in my console project

Comment: then you can refer the already created context class in class library.

Comment: But how? Not sure what to put in the class constructor.

Comment: you can use the default constructor and there you can define